# Binding an array of objects to their specific form fields for updating/deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need to store form data into an array of objects as a link. Then be able to click the link and fill the form with the objects/data to update or delete.

I'm able to store the form data as objects in an array, but can't figure out how to load it back into the form to update.

```
var actors = [];

var addActor = function() {

// Assigning Form values to variables
var firstN = $("#fName").val();
var lastN = $("#lName").val();
var gender = $("[name='gender']:checked").val();
var birthdate = $("#birthDate").val();
var action = $("#action").prop('checked');
var comedy = $("#comedy").prop('checked');
var drama = $("#drama").prop('checked');
var sciencefiction = $("#sciencefiction").prop('checked');
var horror =$("#horror").prop('checked');
var suspense = $("#suspense").prop('checked');

// creates newActor variable that contains an object for each input value
var newActor = {fName: firstN, lName: lastN, gender: gender, birthDate: birthdate, action: action, comedy: comedy, drama: drama, suspense: suspense, sciencefiction: sciencefiction, horror: horror}

$("#actorsTable").append("<tr><td><a href='' class='update'>" + newActor.fName + " " + newActor.lName + "</a></td></tr> ");

actors.push(newActor);

console.log(actors);

};
```

Now my selector function grabs the object but I just don't know how to load it into the form to update and delete. I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

```
var selectActor = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rowClicked = $(this).parent().parent();
    row = rowClicked.index();
    alert (actors[row].fName + " " + actors[row].lName + " " +    actors[row].gender + " " + actors[row].birthDate + " " + actors[row].action + " " + actors[row].comedy + " " + actors[row].drama + " " + actors[row].suspense + " " + actors[row].sciencefiction + " " + actors[row].horror);
    console.log(actors[row]);
};
```

Here is what I have in action so far. When I check console everything is correct with storing, and selecting, but I can't find anything that shows how to store objects into their respected form fields.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/zzzian/pen/oxmzOE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a namespace for your code, then create some generic functions for object manipulations (like an array) as well as some specific to your form.
Note that some libraries like angular, react etc. handle some of this for you, but you asked for the manual part, and it might also be worth some study on one way to do it.

Here is an updated sample to play with: http://codepen.io/MarkSchultheiss/pen/LNqdxK?editors=0010

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.arrayObj = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  },
  remove: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first term has to be removed
      }
    }
  },
  removeByIndex: function(myArray, index) {
    myArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
myApp.func = {
  hasDuplicates: function(actor) {
    var allLast = myApp.arrayObj.lookup(myApp.data.actors, actor.lName, "lName", false);
    var allFirst = myApp.arrayObj.lookup(allLast, actor.fName, "fName", true);
    return !!allFirst.length;
  },
  appendActorRow: function(newActor) {
    myApp.data.actorsTable.append("<tr><td><a href='' class='update' data-actorid='" + newActor.actorId + "'>" + newActor.fName + " " + newActor.lName + "</a></td></tr>");
  },
  getActor: function() {
    var newActor = {
      fName: $("#fName").val(),
      lName: $("#lName").val(),
      gender: $("input[type=radio][name='gender']:checked").val(),
      birthDate: $("#birthDate").val(),
      action: $("#action").prop('checked'),
      comedy: $("#comedy").prop('checked'),
      drama: $("#drama").prop('checked'),
      suspense: $("#suspense").prop('checked'),
      sciencefiction: $("#sciencefiction").prop('checked'),
      horror: $("#horror").prop('checked'),
      actorId: $("#fName").data('actorid')

    }
    return newActor;
  },
  putActor: function(actor) {
    $("#fName").val(actor.fName);
    $("#lName").val(actor.lName);
    $("input[type=radio][name='gender']").val(actor.gender);
    $("#birthDate").val(actor.birthDate);
    $("#action").prop('checked', actor.action);
    $("#comedy").prop('checked', actor.comedy);
    $("#drama").prop('checked', actor.drama);
    $("#suspense").prop('checked', actor.suspense);
    $("#sciencefiction").prop('checked', actor.sciencefiction);
    $("#horror").prop('checked', actor.horror);
    $("#fName").data('actorid', actor.actorId);
  },
  addActor: function(allowDuplicates) {
    var newActor = myApp.func.getActor();
    var validActor = false;
    if (!allowDuplicates && !myApp.func.hasDuplicates(newActor)) {
      validActor = true;
    }
    if (!validActor && allowDuplicates) {
      validActor = true;
    }
    if (validActor) {
      myApp.data.lastActorId = myApp.data.lastActorId + 1;
      newActor.actorId = myApp.data.lastActorId;
      myApp.func.appendActorRow(newActor);
      myApp.data.actors.push(newActor);
    }
    return newActor;
  },
  updateRowByIndex: function(actor, index) {
    myApp.data.actorsTable.eq(index).html(actor.fName + " " + actor.lName).data("actorid", actor.actorId).addClass('update');
  },
  updateRowByActorId: function(actor, actorId) {
    var r = myApp.data.actorsTable.find('a[data-actorid="' + actorId + '"]');
    r.html(actor.fName + " " + actor.lName).data("actorid", actor.actorId).addClass('update');
  },
  clearForm: function() {
    $('#fName').val("");
    $('#lName').val("");
    $('#birthDate').val("");
    $('#form').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
    $('#form').find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", false);
    return this;
  },
  selectActor: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectActorId = $(this).data('actorid');
    var actor = myApp.arrayObj.lookup(myApp.data.actors, selectActorId, "actorId", true)[0];
    myApp.func.putActor(actor);
    myApp.func.setButtons("old")
  },
  updateActor: function() {
    var actor = myApp.func.getActor();
    var index = myApp.arrayObj.indexOf(myApp.data.actors, actor.actorId, "actorId", true);
    if (index != -1) {
      myApp.data.actors[index] = actor;
      myApp.func.updateRowByActorId(actor, actor.actorId);
    }
  },
  deleteActor: function() {
    var actor = myApp.func.getActor();
    var index = myApp.arrayObj.indexOf(myApp.data.actors, actor.actorId, "actorId", true);
    if (index != -1) {
      var r = myApp.data.actorsTable.find('a[data-actorid="' + actor.actorId + '"]');
      r.parents('tr').remove();
      // either will work, used the index one
      //  myApp.arrayObj.remove(myApp.data.actors, actor.actorId, "actorId", true);
      myApp.arrayObj.removeByIndex(myApp.data.actors, index);
    }
    myApp.func.clearForm().setButtons("new");
    // myApp.func.setButtons("new");
  },
  setButtons: function(foo) {
    // if page is new only or form is being filled with new data
    // show 'Add Actor' button only
    $("#addNewActor").toggle((foo === "new"));
    $("#updateActor").toggle(!(foo === "new"));
    $("#deleteActor").toggle(!(foo === "new"));
  }
};
myApp.data = {
  actors: [],
  actorsTable: $("#actorsTable"),
  lastActorId: 0
};
/* end of myApp */

// Function checks state of page and shows/hides buttons
var actorStatex = function(foo) {
  // if page is new only or form is being filled with new data
  // show 'Add Actor' button only
  $("#addNewActor").toggle((foo === "new"));
  $("#updateActor").toggle(!(foo === "new"));
  $("#deleteActor").toggle(!(foo === "new"));
};

var validateForm = function(e) {};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#results').on('click', '.update', myApp.func.selectActor);
  $("#birthDate").datepicker();
  myApp.func.setButtons("new");
  $("#addNewActor").on('click', function() {
    var addedActor = myApp.func.addActor(false);
  });
  $("#updateActor").on('click', myApp.func.updateActor);
  $("#deleteActor").on('click', myApp.func.deleteActor);
  $("#clearButton").on('click', function() {
    myApp.func.clearForm();
    myApp.func.setButtons("new");
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what to say, other than thank you. I probably should have mentioned I'm new to JS, as this is only my 4th lab working with it, so a lot of what you're doing is completely new to me. As Im sure you could tell from my code.

 After reviewing how your namespacing works, I get it to an extent, but I'm going to have to build off this assignment using local storage, and connecting to MySQL database using PHP as well. Do you have any tips or sources on what I could review to help me learn more about how this works or other ways to accomplish the same problem? Thanks again.

Comment: Review https://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/ where he discusses namespacing, and the pattern I used is also there.  The other concepts you can search for topics such as working with arrays of objects (i.e. object arrays).  For this answer, simply review each function for its functionality/merit and don't get overwhelmed by the entire thing.  I grouped the generic stuff in `myApp.arrayObj ` and stuff specific to your functionality in `myApp.func`

Comment: Notice how I broke functions down to do only one thing in instances such as `clearForm: function() {` and `setButtons`, etc.  I can then create/test those and then move on, making it more maintainable.  I could have made the "clearForm" generic by looking for input types as I did on the checkboxes, passed the form name and then used that for example to "scope" by form clear.

Comment: Go read the source code for https://angularjs.org/ , https://facebook.github.io/react/ and other libraries to see how others have done some very nice things. JavaScript is a prototype language search on that and what that means.   Some percentage of coding is ALWAYS about learning more; same with any worthwhile activity. You can also go read the specifications here is a list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources

Comment: Notice I left a `var actorStatex = ` global function in there, I don't use it but then refactored it to the "setButtons" function, so remove it if/when you use this; I only left it to show how I did the refactor of your `.show()` and `.hide()` to use `.toggle` instead

Answer (score 0):

it's because the names of your attributes in your alert doesn't match with those in your newActor object.

You should use alert(actors[row].fName) instead of alert(actors[row].fname)

By the way you could make it really simplier using your form id #actorForm

It should be something like this (I have not tested)

```
var actors = [], index = 0;

$("#addNewActor").click(function() {
     var newActor = $('#actorForm').serialize();

     $("#actorsTable").append("<tr><td><a href='' class='update'>" + newActor.fName + " " + newActor.lName + "</a></td></tr> ");
    actors.push(newActor);
});

// select actor
$(document).on('click', '#actorsTable tr', function() {
    if(actors[$(this).index]) {
        index = $(this).index();
        var actor = actors[index];
        // populate your form
    }
});
$("#updateActor").click(function() {
    var newActor = $('#actorForm').serialize();
    actors[index] = newActor;
});
$("#deleteActor").click(function() {
    actors.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Comment: Yeah that was at typing error, thank you. But that still doesn't help me with loading the objects back into the form for editing/deleting.