# Multidimensional array vs array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, multidimensional-array

I'm building a real estate market simulation running an Agent Based Model and I want to keep track of individual transactions so that I can create graphs and charts and statistic with the data. I was thinking of doing it by using a type of object that I will call `Transaction`:

```
var Transaction = function(house, askingPrice, soldPrice, daysOnMarket) {
    this.date = gameDate
    this.house = house
    this.askingPrice = askingPrice
    this.soldPrice = soldPrice
    this.daysOnMarket = daysOnMarket
};
```

Every time there would be a transaction it would trigger the creation of a new `Transaction` object instance and be pushed to `transArray`:

```
transArray.push (new Transaction(house, askingPrice, soldPrice, daysOnMarket));
```

Is this the best way to accumulate and store this data for my stated purposes or would it be better to use a 2 dimensional array where y would be the `date` and x would be the `house, askingPrice, soldPrice, daysOnMarket`? What do you see as advantages and disadvantages for each method?

Comment: It's up to you. I would personally use an array of objects, but it's not necessarily wrong to use a 2d array.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek What do you see as advantages and disadvantages for each method?

Comment: Whichever is more convenient to you as the developer.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek indeed, while the practical usage is the same, the actual implementation behind both approaches varies. I think OP could potentially want to investigate the implications of memory usage, time complexity, and a whole variety of other concerns.

Comment: As it is, this will fail with `gameDate` not being defined - and I would not use a global in this  case either.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek `gameDate` is defined elsewhere in the code. I just supplied an example of what i was planning to do, not the entire piece of software code for the entire simulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use an array of objects so I can manipulate them using familiar verb functions; like a lookup. There are likely more "pure" Javascript methods to do some of this but I also tested the `lookup`for speed and it is decent in this form.

This is copied from another answer with a more complex example here: [Binding an array of objects to their specific form fields for updating/deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092259/binding-an-array-of-objects-to-their-specific-form-fields-for-updating-deleting/37108576#37108576)

Note on that one for instance the `hasDuplicates` function - so you could easily then support that upon your object array - and if you have more than one object array you can re-use the functions on each one.

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.arrayObj = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  },
  remove: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first term has to be removed
      }
    }
  },
  removeByIndex: function(myArray, index) {
    myArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
```