# Can't find existing object in an array using indexOf in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send the data to the array without existing one. Here is the
code.

```
result.then(function (speaker) { //getting response from the modal
  var speakerdatanew = {_id: speaker._id, name: speaker.name, email: speaker.email};
  if ($scope.speakerdata.indexOf(speakerdatanew._id) === -1) {
    $scope.speakerdata.push(speakerdatanew);
    console.log($scope.speakerdata); 
  } else {
    alert("You have already added speaker");    
  }
});
```

It's continously adding same data multiple times.

Comment: So, the index of the _id in the array of objects is always not there. You're comparing the _id to the object; that's not going to work.

Comment: You cant check with indexOf with an object having multiple attributes.Instead iterate $scope.speakerdata and do the same check for i th element of the iteration.

Comment: If the array is an array of objects, then it only makes sense to pass `indexOf` an object. It will find it if you pass `indexOf` a reference to one of the items in the array. It can't be an object *like* one in the array, it has to be a reference to the actual object in the array. You probably want `Array#some`. `Array#find` is another option if you know the users have a reasonably new browser.

Comment: Actually I am new to Angular, Can you please just elaborate more? @Angular_10

Comment: May I suggest you use lodash or underscorejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find a speaker by `_id`

```
if (!$scope.speakerdata.find(function(s) { return s._id === speakerdatanew._id)) {
    $scope.speakerdata.push(speakerdatanew);
    console.log($scope.speakerdata); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `Array.find` is not supported in Internet Explorer. `Array.some` always works with small changes.

Comment: See [caniuse source](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 1):

An array of objects differs a bit.  This is non AngularJS, just simple JavaScript.

```
 function myIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
   for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
   }
   return -1;
 }
```

Usage

```
if(myIndexOf($scope.speakerdata, speakerdatanew , "_id")===-1){
```

There are other options but this is a simple example.

Note I selfishly pulled this from another answer I created that has examples of removing objects, lookup, lookupall with a link to an even more complex one.  [Multidimensional array vs array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755215/multidimensional-array-vs-array-of-objects/38757114#38757114)

At some point it might serve to use a library or investigate options to these although these do work in older browsers - and I did a small bit of testing for performance in those older browsers having had to support those.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible answers for this problem statement but I 've went for simpler approach where I can perform different actions at each step of checking if the object is present or not.Below is the sample snippet for your question.

You can even use `angular.forEach`   for iterating list

```
angular.forEach($scope.speakerdata, function(val, key) {

            });
```

But there is no facility for break or continue keywords in that so I didn't use.

```
 .result.then(function (speaker) { //getting response from the modal
        var speakerdatanew = {
            _id: speaker._id,
            name: speaker.name,
            email: speaker.email
        };

        var alreadyPresent = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.speakerdata.length; i++) {
            var speakerData = $scope.speakerdata[i];
            if (speakerData._id == speakerdatanew._id) {
                alreadyPresent = true;
                break;
            } else {

            }
        }
        if (alreadyPresent) {
            alert("You have already added speaker");
        } else {
            $scope.speakerdata.push(speakerdatanew);
            console.log($scope.speakerdata);
        }
```